# reactjs not loading on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, create-react-app

My react web app is not loading on iOS, especially v15.5.

Only black page is loaded when I access to the website using iPhone or iPad.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you using any regex ?

Comment: yes im using several regexes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because of regex usage. Looks like Safari doesn't support lookbehind yet (that is, your (?<=/)). One alternative would be to put the / that comes before in a non-captured group, and then extract only the first group (the content after the / and before the #).

```
/(?:\/)([^#]+)(?=#*)/
```

Also, (?=#*) is odd - you probably want to lookahead for something (such as # or the end of the string), rather than a * quantifier (zero or more occurrences of #). It might be better to use something like

```
/(?:\/)([^#]+)(?=#|$)/
```

or just omit the lookahead entirely (because the ([^#]+) is greedy), depending on your circumstances.